# How to write async/await in return statement of vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I originally had this code:

```
export function InitActions($api) {
  return {
    [partnersMts.PARTNERS_LIST]({commit, state}) {
      if (!state.partnersList || state.partnersList.length === 0) {
        $api.partners.partnersList().then(result => {
          commit(partnersMts.PARTNERS_LIST, result.data);
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to rewrite it with async/await, I tried this:

```
export function InitActions($api) {
  return {
    async [partnersMts.PARTNERS_LIST]({commit, state}) {
      if (!state.partnersList || state.partnersList.length === 0) {
        await $api.partners.partnersList()
        commit(partnersMts.PARTNERS_LIST, result.data);
      }
    },
   }
}
```

But I get an error: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: result is not defined`
On the commit line above, this inidcates that the code is not waiting for the call to complete, what am I writing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the result of the await into the `result` variable:

```es6
const result = await $api.partners.partnersList()
commit(partnersMts.PARTNERS_LIST, result.data)
```